# If a Triple Graph Grammar rule counts as a Mathematical Proof

Tags: graphs, formal-grammars, proof-techniques, software-verification

I am intrigued by [Triple Graph Grammars](http://www.wagner-gt.de/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/KW07.pdf) (TGG) as a potential for formal mathematical proof.

> Triple Graph Grammars (TGGs) are a technique for defining the
>   correspondence between two different types of models in a declarative
>   way.

In some systems, proofs are simply trees of rules being applied to transform one syntax tree of terms into another. *I don't really have a firm grasp of what that actually means in practice, but I think I understand the gist of it.* As such, a proof is a transformation of a into b, so a correspondence between two different models. Some sort of *isomorphism*.

The diagrams below show (roughly) that there are links between source and target objects, defining how to transform them (bijection). I'm wondering if a TGG rule has enough information in it to allow it to be considered a valid proof of a transformation of isomorphism. That is, *and I don't fully understand how to apply TGGs*, you define a TGG between two forms of an object (or more generally, between two objects), and that definition is equivalent to a formal proof of the isomorphism between the two objects. Wondering if this is true or if it is close to true. If close / along the lines of the right direction, wondering what it would require to make it into a valid proof.

To summarize, the questions are:

1. If a TGG counts as a valid proof of **transformation** (maybe of isomorphism) from $A \to B$.
2. If a TGG counts as a valid proof of transformation from $B \to A$.
3. If not, what would be required to make it into a valid proof.

---

Some more notes are:

> A triple graph $G =(G_S \overset{s_G}{\longleftarrow} G_C \overset{t_G}{\longrightarrow} G_T)$ consists of three graphs $G_S$, $G_C$, and $G_T$, called source, correspondence, and target graphs, together with two graph morphisms $s_G : G_C \to G_S$ and $t_G : G_C \to G_T$. A triple graph morphism $m = (m_S, m_C , m_T) : G \to H$ consists of three graph morphisms $m_S : G_S \to H_S$, $m_C : G_C \to H_C$ and $m_T : G_T \to H_T$ such that $m_S \circ s_G = s_H \circ m_C$ and
>   $m_T \circ t_G = t_H \circ m_C$. A typed triple graph $G$ is typed over a triple graph $T_G$ by a triple graph morphism $type_G : G \to T_G$. [[source](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/85be/f51497c2f739b0138f9f3730dda687b8dac6.pdf)]

A function transforming A into B doesn't keep track of the actual individual steps between transformation, so the information is lost. But the TGG does. The only way to "prove" that A can be transformed to B with a function is to actually apply the function and compare the outputs. But with a mapping defined in a TGG, the "proof" would be the mapping itself, so you don't have to actually perform the transformation (or it seems). So given A and B and R (rule) in TGG context, R is the proof, we don't have to try converting A $\to$ B.

An example of this would be the transform between a parse tree and an abstract syntax tree. The parse tree let's say is the actual individual tokens organized into a tree of symbols and words, where every object in the tree is the same type of object (let's say a "parse node" object). The AST though is a tree of custom objects like "function node" and "variable node". So you convert the parse tree to the AST. How to prove that AST came from the parse tree. A function requires recomputing the output, maybe a TGG rule means it's automatically proven as a "derivation" of the parse tree.

Given I have parse tree A and AST B in memory, I would like to be able to say "A becomes B" without having to recompute it. I would like to say "B came from A" as well, which seems possible because of the bidirectional mapping of TGGs.

---

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TGG defines (generates) a language of triples of graphs.
This can be used for many things, including establishing a notion of correctness for forward and backward transformations.  So if you have some transformation A -> B, you can check if it is correct by checking if there exists some A <-C->B that can be generated by the TGG.

Correct forward and backward transformations do not have to be bijections, although this could be enforced by analysing the TGG appropriately.

As a proof, one could use a TGG to generate proofs of consistency.  So given some A and B, I can prove that A and B are consistent (and whatever produced B from A or A from B correct), by determining a rule application sequence that takes you from some start triple graph to some A<-C->B.

So for your concrete syntax tree and AST you could check for consistency without recomputing the trees.  In practice, however, such a consistency checker can actually be slower than a recomputation (but is sometimes still better, e.g., if the computation was non-deterministic or required some form of decision making).

Comment: Welcome to the site!